# Sync data between Android App and MongoDB on webserver

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, mobile, synchronization

I am developing such an App that will create some extra data on local mobile app from user end. Say user 1 did something, he earned 1 reward on his app, I need that extra 1 coin sync with my server, ideally a mongoDB which stores userID and userCoinNumber. So in mongoDB on server it will say user1 has 1 coin left.

However, during this process many issue might happen, for example sync issue happens when user is offline and he created 1 coin, that coin might not be updated on server. Also, when too many users are using app at the same time, the mongoDB could crash(?) due to large traffic between server and app. Is there some general suggestion, like alternative to mongoDB or anything else that you guys think I should do?